# Unable to update ADO.NET entity framework

Tags: c#

After adding the framework to my project I am unable to add more tables to the framework. Tried "updating model from database" in the database design in Visual Studio but it does not save the new table I want to add though it sees the new table in the database that is not in my model but does not add it

Comment: When you say "trying to update my ADO.NET framework".... do you mean upgrading to a newer version of EF?

Comment: No i mean updating the model to enable a new tabke i created in my database.

Comment: I get the same problem many times so I had to delete the ADO.NET object and create a new one every time I make changes to the database. Sometimes updating the model by right click -> update it works, but make sure to build the project afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Sir my bad forgot did not add a primary key. Very grateful